# Convert seconds to years in R

Tags: r, date

If I have a large number of seconds, such as 4*10^17 to estimate the age of the universe, and I want to convert it to years, how would I do that? Is there a function command in R to do this or would it just be by doing the math? I tried using the lubridate package, but I couldn't find anything.  seconds_to_period resulted in days, hours, minutes, seconds.  I can't seem to figure out duration and if that would be a good call to use.

Comment: Do you also have a start date / end date?  you can look into the lubridate package, which is great for dates, but if you need an exact reponse (taking into account leap years) you need a from/to date

Comment: @User632716, the start date is Monday October 14, 4115 BC.

Answer (score 3):

In a year you have 31557600 seconds.

You can do 4*10^17/31557600

Have a look on [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/time/seconds-in-year.html)

```
4*10^17/31557600
[1] 12675235126
```

Comment: The number `4x10^17` is astronomical, and you would probably want to take into account things like leap seconds, leap minutes, etc.  I think the formula you need is more complex than this.

Comment: I strongly disagree about leap seconds. The input is an estimate of the age of the universe with one significant digit. You could simplify the `31557600` to `3.2e7` and be fine. Leap seconds would just give you a completely false sense of precision.

Comment: In the question Lost ask how to "convert it to years", so this is basic math. I agree with @Gregor, precision in this topic is not related to leap seconds but millions of years.

Answer (score 1):

The closest i can find to a prebuilt function is seconds_to_period:

```
lubridate::seconds_to_period(2121654654)
```

You should be careful with a simple calculation(depending on the level of accuracy that you need), as this won't account for leapyears.  Remember that there are actually 365.25 days in a calendar year.

Comment: 365.25 days in a calendar year, on average, approximately

Comment: The OP has mentioned in his question that he already has tried `lubridate::seconds_to_period()` but it does return days, not years as requested. BTW: `lubridate::seconds_to_period(4*10^17)` returns  `"4629629629629d 15H 6M 40S"`.

Answer (score 1):

There is the `simtimer` package that allows you to convert seconds to years. (Referenced to a `origin_date`). So the following tells you the number of years between today and 4*10^16 seconds in future.

```
lubridate::year(simtimer::as.datetime(4*10^16, origin_date = Sys.time())) - 
lubridate::year(Sys.time())
[1] 316887385
```

The thing however is, that with 4*10e17 it throws a `NA`. I think because it is too big of a number. So most possibly you have to stick with @Terru_theTerrors solution

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, 4*10e17 is too large, but thank you! I did not know about the simtimer package!